# Getting Values from web.config file to rdlc report?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

How to get the values from web.config (appsettings) file to my rdlc report?
I need to show multiple values in my rdlc invoice where they are coming from web.config file? How can I get on this one?

```
<add key="siteName" value="desktopapplications" />
<add key="companyName" value="ProSoftware Limited" />
```

where can I write the code  in rdlc and how to implement the above values?

I know how to get the values from web.config to .cs page

```
string siteName= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteName"]
```

How it works in rdlc? Any help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Lon Prosser Answer

```
       using (var lr = new LocalReport())
        {

            var path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Report", "MyInvoice.rdlc");
            lr.ReportPath = path;
            var siteName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteName"];
            var companyName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["companyName"];

            var @params = new ReportParameter[2];

            @params[0] = new ReportParameter("siteName", siteName);
            @params[1] = new ReportParameter("companyName",companyName);
            var usersinv = db.Invoices.Where(i => i.Id == invoiceid.Id);
            var invoice = usersinv.SingleOrDefault();
            if (invoice != null)
            {
                var invoiceitems = db.InvoiceItems.Where(i => i.InvoiceId == invoiceid.Id);
                var rd1 = new ReportDataSource("Invoice", usersinv);
                var rd2 = new ReportDataSource("InvoiceItems", invoiceitems.ToList());

                lr.DataSources.Add(rd1);
                lr.DataSources.Add(rd2);
                lr.SetParameters(@params);
            }
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtention;

            const string deviceInfo =
            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.0cm</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.0cm</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0.0cm</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.0cm</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render("PDF",
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtention,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


        }
        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

Now, the parameters in the PDF invoice will be invoked by web.config file

Answer (score 1):

In the RDLC designer in the Report Data panel, add parameters for siteName and companyName. In the code behind:

```
Dim myReport As New LocalReport
Dim params() As ReportParameter = New ReportParameter(1) {}
     params(0) = New ReportParameter("siteName", siteName)
     params(1) = New ReportParameter("companyName", companyName)
With myReport
    .ReportPath = ReportPath '"MyReport.rdlc"
    .DataSources.Clear()
    .DataSources.Add(mydatasource)
    .Refresh()
    .SetParameters(params)
End With
```